# Best Way to Get Rid of Ceprolad.A

Tags: virus, anti-virus, virus-removal, trojan

Well this is embarrassing...  I was attempting to download a freeware tool and clicked on the wrong thing so I was blasted with tons of malware.  Windows Defender seems to have gotten rid of some of it, but one program Ceprolad.A refuses to go away.

What is the best way to get rid of Ceprolad.A without spending money or reformatting my HD?

Comment: I know that you don't want to reinstall Windows, but if you don't have backups, it's the only reliable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Defender is supposed to be able of eradicating the
[Trojan:Win32/Ceprolad.A](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Trojan:Win32/Ceprolad.A),
but maybe the virus has evolved into a new format.

Your only option is to try out other anti-virus products, one after the other,
until the virus is gone. I advice running more than one anti-virus,
even if the virus seems to have been removed, just in case it left something
behind.

If you have a System Restore backup dating to before the infection,
rolling back to it will also help.

The only sure solution is to format the disk and reinstall everything,
but this may be too difficult.

For more information, see the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)